# Textbox with input is too small

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a search text input box where the input text is the same size, font, and style as the placeholder.

Searching the internet found little to point me in the right direction.

Here is my code:

```css
::placeholder {
 color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
 font-family: Moon;
 font-size: 20px;
 padding-left: 5%;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Search..." name="searchInput" id="searchBar"><br />
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKEwT.jpg

When you go on to type text, it should have the same style as the placeholder.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a minimal example, all properties must be added to the `input`, and set only the color for `placeholder`.

```css
input {
  background: black;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  font-family: Courier;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-top: 2%;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  /* WebKit, Blink, Edge */
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}

:-moz-placeholder {
  /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  opacity: 1;
}

::-moz-placeholder {
  /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  opacity: 1;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
  /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}

::-ms-input-placeholder {
  /* Microsoft Edge */
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}

::placeholder {
  /* Most modern browsers support this now. */
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Search..." name="searchInput" id="searchBar">
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```css
#searchBar {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  font-family: Moon;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 0 0 0 5%;

  background:transparent;
  border:0;
  outline: none;
  border:1px solid white;
  border-radius:20px;
}
#searchBar::placeholder {
  color:inherit;
}
body {
  background:#4267b2;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Search..." name="searchInput" id="searchBar">
```

Comment: This is using a div to simulate placeholder, what happens when user backspaces what he typed and input is empty? Does the placeholder text show?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava Good point. I edited my answer and upvoted yours.